# Still having troube with jquery Image rollovers

Tags: jquery, rollovers

Ok I am still having some issues with this code below. I have received some guidance from some SO users and I appreciate that.

However, I am still perplexed with what I am doing wrong here. I have a basic rollover jquery script using images. However, when the user clicks one of the images I want that image to stay in the “active/clicked” state. If another image is clicked I want that one in the “active/clicked” state and the previously active/clicked image to go back to the off state.

Basically, I want this to work like a tab control Off, On, Active. 
The code below works with the exception of the clicks. When I click on the image it turns “active”. But when I click on another image it does not toggle the previously clicked image so I end up with all the images in the “active” state. I have tried everything I can think of and have searched google for the answer but everything I try ends up with the same result. All the images stay “active” when clicked instead of toggling.

Can someone please take a look and help me figure out what I am missing here. I just started with jquery and I am still learning my way around.  By the way I know that this can be done with CSS but since I am trying to learn I would rather understand what I am doing wrong then just moving on to another method. So please do not suggest that I do this with CSS as an answer. 
Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var sel;
    $("#nav a").mouseover(function() {
        if ( $(this).data("clicked") ) { return; }
        $(this).children("img").each(function() {
            this.src = $(this).attr("src").replace(/_off.gif$/ig,"_on.gif");
        });
    }).mouseout(function() {
        if ( $(this).data("clicked") ) { return; }
        $(this).children("img").each(function() {
            this.src = $(this).attr("src").replace(/_on.gif$/ig,"_off.gif");
        });
    //handle clicks
    }).click(function() {
        if( sel != null ) {
        $(this).children("img").each(function() {
            this.src = $(this).attr("src").replace(/_clk.gif$/ig,"_off.gif");

        });
        }
        $(this).children("img").each(function() {
            this.src = $(this).attr("src").replace(/_on.gif$/ig,"_clk.gif");
        })
        sel = this;
    });


}); 


</script>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="nav">
            <div id="logo"><img src="images/inbox_wrilogo.gif" width="143" height="30" alt="logo" border="0"  /></div>
            <div id="tab"><a href="#"><img src="images/nav_support_off.gif" width="75" height="22"  alt="Support" name="support" border="0"/></a></div>
            <div id="tab"><a href="#"><img src="images/nav_acct_off.gif" width="75" height="22" alt="My Account" name="acct" border="0" /></a></div>
            <div id="tab"><a href="#"><img src="images/nav_inbox_off.gif" width="75" height="22" alt="Inbox" name="inbox" border="0" /></a></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - Your click function will need to look at all the images in `#nav` to see which one is clicked and turn it off.

Instead of:

> ```
> $(this).children("img").each(function() {
>             this.src = $(this).attr("src").replace(/_clk.gif$/ig,"_off.gif");
>
>         });
> ```

Try:

```
$("#nav").find("img").each(function() {
  this.src = this.src.replace(/_clk\.gif$/i, "_off.gif");
});
```

Also - Two things to point out: First the `.` character should be escaped `\.` in your regexp. Second: if you are using this.src = why not just replace on this.src as well?